# AWS IAM Allow user to manipulate only with lambdas with certain prefix in name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I figured out how to do it for for example update function etc. (just with  `arn:aws:lambda:*:account-id:function:prefix_*`) but it did not work for create function. I guess it's because create function does not has ARN... but how to solve this?

Thanks for help! :)